# In decapsulation process in TCP/IP, are IP packets merged back before passing to Application Layer?

Tags: http, tcp

As known, in decapsulation process, a message follows Data link, Network, Transport and Application Layers, and the question is while decapsulating a request/response data in HTTP, does Application Layer get the message as a whole or Transport Layer sends up as it receives?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a message in TCP. It is a byte-stream protocol. You get bytes.

Comment: I meant "sending" or "receiving" data.

Comment: In TCP, there is no 1-to-1 correlation between sends and receives.  The sender could send 1 100-byte buffer, and the receiver could potentially receive 100 1-byte packets.  TCP is a stream of bytes, there is no concept of message boundaries.  The transport layer provides raw bytes, the application layer has to merge them back together into understandable messages.

Comment: @CanMingir It doesn't matter what you meant. The facts are independent of your intention.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, that was a good answer. I am testing like I have 10MB text file in a server, when I open it with IE browser, it displays right away and keeps loading page at the bottom as it downloads. I was expecting it loads once fully, then displays.

Comment: That is dependent on the protocol (HTTP in your comment), the type of data being transferred (HTML vs JS vs images), etc. Web browsers try to parse data as it is being received, but that is not always possible. And web servers might deliver files in chunks, so web browsers might not even know up front how much data is going to be received.  For a simple text file, it makes sense that a web browser can render the text data as it is being downloaded. That might make sense for other types of data. And this is not necessarily a good example of how all TCP applications behave in general.